# how to calculate the average processing time in nginx

Tags: http, nginx

I wish to calculate the average processing time of requests going through nginx. More specifically, it would be awesome to get various percentiles. and it would be even better if I could get these by HTTP method (post/get etc).

I do have a bunch of bad/not-so-great solutions:

1. forgo nginx and do this math from the loadbalancer's logs
2. expose each requests's processing time in the nginx access log, ship it and then process it (or just do it locally with cron/bash).

but there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a good (and free!) solution: a combination of nginx, nginx-statsd-module and statsd. The general idea is to use the nginx-statsd module to transmit the processing time from nginx into a statsd server (and from there, to whatever data collection mechanism you use).

With the statsd module (https://github.com/kinecosystem/nginx-statsd), you can configure nginx to emit the processing time per HTTP method, per nginx location:

```
statsd_timing "your_product.$request_method.index_response_time" "$upstream_response_time";
```

the results, as printed by statsd, look something like this:

```
      timer_data:
   { 'your_product.GET.index_response_time':
      { count_90: 2,
        mean_90: 1002,
        upper_90: 1004,
        sum_90: 2004,
        sum_squares_90: 2008016,
        std: 2,
        upper: 1004,
        lower: 1000,
        count: 2,
        count_ps: 0.2,
        sum: 2004,
        sum_squares: 2008016,
        mean: 1002,
        median: 1002 } },
  counter_rates:
   { 'statsd.bad_lines_seen': 0,
     'statsd.packets_received': 0.2,
     'statsd.metrics_received': 0.2 },
  sets: {},
```

using the module requires a somewhat elaborate compilation, but it does work. tested with nginx 1.14.0.

Comment: Interesting - I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to get different statistics on the Nginx performance. There is a **non-free** [nginx-amplify-doc](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-amplify-doc/blob/master/amplify-guide.md#metrics-and-metadata) that can get you what you want. I am not sure what is the pricing policy there - **I ended up parsing the access logs because I did not wanted to pay for such service.**

The nginx.http.request.time metric in this tool can get you exactly what you want. You may check the pricing there, maybe it is free for a small scale support.

> Type:        gauge, seconds.milliseconds
>   Description: Request processing time — time elapsed between reading the first bytes from
>                the client and writing a log entry after the last bytes were sent.
>   Source:      access.log (requires custom log format)
>   Variable:    $request_time

[image]

Comment: thank you for this comment! didn't realise this was possible, but I'd much rather find a free solution.